# 'ReferenceError: contents is not defined' with U1db

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-sdk, qml

I'm trying to read information from a database of U1db.
I encountered this error
 `'ReferenceError: contents is not defined'`
Here's my code:

```
    import U1db 1.0 as U1db
    U1db.Database {
            id: db
            path: "lU1DbDatabase"
        }
    U1db.Document {
            id: doc
            database: db
            docId: 'doc1'
            create: true
            defaults: { "name":["Jerusalem"]}
        }
    U1db.Index{
            database: db
            id: index1
            expression: [["name"]]
        }
    U1db.Query{
            id: query1
            index: index1
        }
     OptionSelector {
                id:selector1
                model:query1
                delegate: OptionSelectorDelegate {
                                    text: i18n.tr(contents.name)//this work perfect
                                }
                onSelectedIndexChanged: {
                    console.log(contents.name);//this get the error!
                }
   }
```

this is part of large code that i cut the part that cause the problem.
what am i doing wrong? thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is not with U1DB, but with the OptionSelector.  Let's consider a simpler example:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import Ubuntu.Components 1.0

MainView {
    OptionSelector {
        model: ListModel {
            ListElement { name: "Item 1" }
            ListElement { name: "Item 2" }
        }
        delegate: OptionSelectorDelegate {
            text: i18n.tr(name)
        }
        onSelectedIndexChanged: {
            console.log(name)
        }
    }
}
```

When the index is changed, we get the error, "ReferenceError: name is not defined".  And why would we expect it to be defined?  We've defined no variable named "name", and the OptionSelector doesn't have a "name" property.

Why can we reference "name" in the delegate?  A new object is created from the delegate for each element in the model.  This object gets the properties from that list element, and our list elements contain a "name" property.  Similarly, in your example, the U1db.Query produced list elements with a "contents" property, which evidently was an object with a "name" property.

If we want to reference those properties outside of the delegate, we need to reach into the model and extract them:

```
            console.log(model.get(selectedIndex).name)
```

In your case, the model is a U1db.Query, not a ListModel, so it doesn't have a `get()` method.  It does have a `results` list that I presume you can index, but I don't know enough about U1db to say more.  Hopefully this is enough to get you on the right path.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this line has solved the problem for me:   `var doc = loacationDatabase.getDoc(model.documents[selectedIndex]);` it stores the whole document into a variable and then I can read all the data.    i think this is the best solution that i have.

Comment: or just `model.results[selectedIndex].name[0]`